# I'm looking for a canonical question on call blocking to help clean up the main site

Tags: discussion

We've had many, many questions about call blocking and most of them are quite outdated.

I've tried to find the best canonical question and this is the one I propose we maintain as the primary target for closing duplicates.

- [Call blocking for iPhone?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/34157/call-blocking-for-iphone)

It's the simplest, least convoluted, and also fairly old and well indexed already by major search engines.

I'll post an answer with the duplicates I've closed there (no merging yet)

Comment: Looks good!  Let's upvote the new answer (that takes advantage of iOS 7 features), too, so it bubbles to the top.  Great job!

Comment: I made my post CW so I don't get any rep from that post.